# Field, Euclidean division question.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, field-theory

Let $K$ be a field and $f \in K[x]$. Show that if there is some $a \in K$ such that $f(a)=0$, then $x-a$ divides $f$.

My friend told me to use Euclidean division by $x-a$.

Also show that a polynomial $f \in K[x]$ of degree of two or three is irreducible if and only if it has no root in $K$.

Note: This was the last assignment (due date already passed [April 30] so I'm not directly asking for hw answers) for my introduction to abstract algebra course. I'm posting it here because my professor decided not to post solutions for this last assignment since she'll be busy making the final exam. Still, I feel like these questions are very relevant and may pop up on the final.

Lastly:

$p$ is a prime number that is not the sum of two squares. Show that $p$ is prime in the ring $\mathbb{Z}[i]$. Give an example of a prime number which is not prime in $\mathbb{Z}[i]$.

Comment: Your edit isn't really relevant to this question - it is its own question.

Answer (score 1):

You know you can write $f(x)=(x-a)g(x)+r(x)$, and then $0=f(a)=(a-a)g(a)+r(a)=r(a)$. But you know that the degree of $r$ is less than the degree of $x-a$, so $r$ is constant, and $r=0$.

Your second point is that any reducible polynomial of degree two or three must have at least one linear factor, say $x-a$. A quadratic polynomial is reducible if it factors into two linear factors, and a cubic can either factor into three linear factors, or one linear and one irreducible quadratic. You can see above that this is the case when $f$ has a root in $K$.